# Requests - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I have a list of 2500 URLs for which I'm trying to obtain text data using.

```py
def request_until_succeed(url):
    connection_success = False
    tries = 1
    while connection_success is False:
        request = requests.session()
        retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        request.mount('http://', adapter)
        request.mount('https://', adapter)
        try:
            request = requests.get(url, verify=False)
            connection_success = True
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(5*tries)
            tries += 1
            print('\n Retrying connection for {url}: \n {error}:'.format(url=url, error=e))
    return request
```

The problem is that everytime I reach the 220th link, I get the following error even after many tries with increasing sleep times.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.WEBSITE.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /REST/OF/URL (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x131fd5eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

A big issue is that I'm not able to reproduce the error since plugging that 220th URL individually into the function I used above works just fine so I've discarded any issues with my IP or that particular URL.

I'm not using any proxies, VPNs or anything and as you can see I'm restarting the requests session for every URL.